# Django 1.8 Operational error : no such table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I found lot of similar questions/answer which suggested to use "migrate" and "makemigrations" but that didnt work. Im using python 2.7 and pycharm 4.5.4 as IDE.
when i created a new model for product imagefield,registered to admin and I ran "makemigrations" and then "migrate" and then i got this error OperationalError at /admin/products/productimage/
no such table: products_productimage. What am I missing here ? Below is

## model.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save


    # Create your models here.

    class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
        def active(self):
            return self.filter(active=True)


    class ProductManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self.db)

        def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.get_queryset().active()


    class Product(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        objects = ProductManager()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
            # OR use this- return "/product/%s"%(self.pk)


    class Variation(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product)  ##this means each Variation is related to single product
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
        sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # default=-1 means unlimited

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_price(self):
            if self.sale_price is not None:
                return self.sale_price
            else:
                return self.price

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return self.product.get_absolute_url()


    # for post save receiver


    def product_saved_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        # sender=modelclass, instance=actual instance being saved,created=boolean true if record was created
        product = instance
        variations = product.variation_set.all()
        if variations.count() == 0:
            new_var = Variation()
            new_var.product = product
            new_var.title = "Default"
            new_var.price = product.price
            new_var.save()


    post_save.connect(product_saved_receiver, sender=Product)


    # product image
    # you need to install python pillow library to support. it checks if file uploaded is actually an image and checks extension
    class ProductImage(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.product.title
```

## the admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Product, Variation, ProductImage

    # Register your models here.
    admin.site.register(Product)
    admin.site.register(Variation)
    admin.site.register(ProductImage)
```

Output of makemigrations and migrate

```
manage.py@dj > makemigrations
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Anaconda\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" makemigrations C:/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/dj
    No changes detected

    Process finished with exit code 0
    manage.py@dj > migrate
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Anaconda\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" migrate C:/Users/user1/PycharmProjects/dj
    Operations to perform:
      Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, messages, crispy_forms
      Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes, products, registration, newsletter
    Synchronizing apps without migrations:
      Creating tables...
        Running deferred SQL...
      Installing custom SQL...
    Running migrations:
      No migrations to apply.

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

## on browser i get below error[image]

Comment: Can you show the output of those commands as you ran them?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco i have updated the post. cheers

Comment: Probably not related, but did you mean for `def product_saved_receiver...` and `post_save.connect...` to be indented one level further?

Comment: Just to confirm: do you get any migrations created when explicitly specifying your app? `makemigrations products`

Comment: @mfcovington   i think the indentation is correct. i was using django admin to upload image and got this error

Comment: when i execute  "makemigrations products"  the output is-> No changes detected in app 'products'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about losing your data, you can delete the SQLite3 file and run the 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' commands again. You will probably also have to recreate a superuser (python manage.py createsuperuser)

Comment: Heres how it worked for me, i deleted the "db.sqlite3", and also  files inside the app-name->migrations->0001_initial.py ,  0002_XXX.py  , run "makemigrations" and then "migrate"

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `migrate <yourapp> zero --fake` and then once again `migrate <yourapp>`? This worked for me, I had the same issue.